# Intel Rapid Storage Technology RAID Setup always shows on system startup

Tags: boot, raid

Is there a way of getting the `Press <CTRL - I>` screen to not show on startup? Or is it permanently there as long as I have RAID?

Comment: It will show up even if you didn't it shows up because you have a hardware raid controller

Comment: @ramhound - What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you have UEFI bios then access it, enter advanced mode, navigate to BOOT tab,find "Option ROM messages" and change it from "Force BIOS" to "Keep current".
Don't ask me why. Found it [here](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?52590-Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Screen-on-Boot) when i had the same issue and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the bios for the raid controller would be concidered nessisary prior to the OS drivering the hardware raid.  Different versions of it are faster or slower for the time that bios screen shows, It is possible that a bios update for the motherboard (assuming it is onboard) changes things, but not likely.

**Added after having missed the Point completly:** I have never yet seen a switch to disable the "press CTRL-I" for the intel bios, like one could find in other motherboard options to "disable showing Press DEL or F2" settings.  If it did exist it would be right there in that bios, going to CTRL-I and looking for any possible settings for the display of that.

Other raid card items can have an even longer time they display for giving you a chance to get into the bios for the hardware item. It is better to have this screen than to not be able to get into the bios at this low level.  There can also be diagnostics including SMART going on at this low level that could be very useful.

The screen showing is not as nessiary as the operations of this software , keeping the array items assembled via hardware represented and acting as the team , prior to being in the Operating system and drivered.  I have ripped out a hardware bios operation for an external card, and the raid still exists, but the assembly of the items was not available till after getting to the OS, so there was no longer a way to Boot to the raid.

Some bios for raid can be bypassed or skipped , to get rid of the screen quicker, like some high-point controller the END button would jump past aspects of the scanning.  I do not think that any of the intel ones have this feature where a ESC or END or some F? button would skip past some aspects of it. If your booting to it and gaining disgnostics (even ones you have yet to see) you really wouldnt want to miss it.

It is part of having hardware raid and the screen should be observed more as knowledge that it is operational, knowing that the array is functional (if it has that feature).  This is a good thing, enjoy it :-)   The one your seeing is probably a lot quicker than some stuff out there, and having 2 makes it all the more fun.  Bios never has to be nice looking, it is better that it stays working right and simple.

Comment: No one left a comment after downvoting you, so rather than also downvoting you I'll just explain why: The question is asking to get rid of the screen, and your reply is saying "Well you shouldn't want to do that anyway," which is just dismissive, not helpful.